# Return R object given its name

Tags: r

Given the name of an R object (as a string), how can I return the object with that name?

(The context in which this comes up is that I am running the function findGlobals, which returns a vector objects as a strings. I would like to then iterate through the list and test to make sure each name refers to a function using is.function. If you know of a solution to this specific problem without the more general question above, that would also be appreciated.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get()` is what you're looking for. And by "iterate" I assume you mean using an apply variant, e.g.

```
sapply(ls(), FUN = function(x) is.function(get(x)))
```

Comment: Also a possibility is `sapply(mget(ls()), is.function)`

Comment: Thank you, that's precisely what I was looking for.